# SQL Server : Lookup / Join on variable length string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that will return the closest match from a table. The table represents a hierarchy, and looks like this:

```
Hier_Code Group1 Group2 Group3
_________ ______ ______ ______
A         1      1      5 
AA        1      2      5
AAA       1      2      5
AAB       1      3      5
AB        2      3      5
ABA       2      3      5
ABB       2      3      5
```

The values I'm searching for may not match perfectly, in which case I'd want them to 'roll-up' to the next level to find the match.  For example:

```
Value     Returns:  
A         1      1      5 (Perfect match)
AAC       1      2      5 (AA is closest)
AABB      1      3      5 (AAB is closest)
```

The idea is that you would strip off one character at a time from the search term until you find a match. I've tried doing this with a recursive CTE, and also with a WHILE loop to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT top 1 Group1, Group2, Group3 
FROM temp 
WHERE 'AABB' like Hier_Code + '%'
GROUP BY Group1, Group2, Group3
ORDER BY MAX(len(Hier_Code)) desc
```

Comment: Hi Lieven,   Thanks for the quick reply.  Your solution seems to work when the Hier_code is short, but when I tested it with a code that has sever characters (perfect match except for last character), it failed, returning the row for top of that hierarchy.

Comment: @user1456921, this is my answer not Lieven's.  Could you post the Hier_Code that is not working, the row that should be returned and the row that is actually being returned.

Comment: Sorry Abe. The code I'm searching for is DFCGAAX, it should have matched on DFCGAA.  When I run it, it's returning the data for D (top level)

Comment: The updated ORDER BY seems to have fixed it.  Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starter that you could use to create some dynamic SQL:

```
           select id from t
           where g1 = 1 and g2 = 1 and g3 = 5

           union

           select id from t
           where g1 = 1 and g2 = 1 

           union

           select id from t
           where g1 = 1
```

The default behavior of UNION is to eliminate duplicates, so that after these three selects are executed, no id would occur more than once in the result set.

The problem is that there are several permutations:

```
         {g1, g2, g3}, {g1, g3},  {g1, g2}, {g2, g3}
```

so you cannot simply pluck the final condition off as I did in my example.